# Where to place the constants

Tags: ruby-on-rails, slim-lang

```
Rails 3.2
```

I have some some constants that I would like to use in my Rails project. They are string constants. I placed them in lib/code_constants.rb

```
confirm_payment = 'Confirm Payment'
```

In my view (using SLIM), I put the following as the first line:

```
- include CodeContants
= form_for(@payments, url: payment_path) do |f|
.....
.actions = f.submit confirm_payment
```

I am getting the following error message:

Expected /app/lib/code_constants.rb to define CodeConstants

I am somewhat new to SLIM, but I thought that by including the file here, I can use the constants in my view

Answer (score 1):

I guess that you didn't require this file in `application.rb`.

In `application.rb` put this code.

```
config.autoload_paths << "#{Rails.root}/lib"
```

Then, in `code_constants.rb`, you can write as:

```
module CodeConstants
 confirm_payment = 'Confirm Payment'
end
```

And in you view file, you can use your constant following as:

```
= form_for(@payments, url: payment_path) do |f|
.....
.actions = f.submit CodeConstants::confirm_payment
```

Answer (score 0):

Rails' Internationalization is much more suited to this use case than defining constants. Check out the guide at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html.

Comment: No it is not. This is only one example. There are reasons why you want to make certain constants non-localizable

Comment: Of course, I'm not suggesting replacing all your constants with translations. Still, your example here - defining the text to be displayed on UI elements in views - is exactly what i18n is intended for.